# RESTful related resource using JSONAPI schema

Tags: rest, json-api

I am following the [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org) schema to return a standardised response from a web API. I want to reduce the number of HTTP requests to get related information so it looks like I want to use [compound documents](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) to return (for example) an article and two related comments.

I somewhat understand this but I am wondering what the RESTful GET request would be? I am thinking something like

```
http://api.mysite.com/v1/articles/1?comments=2
```

I like to be explicit but are the request parameters necessary in order to return related information from a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you want /v1/articles/1?include=comments&limitComments=2

Where limitComments is an API-specific param (note member name requirements)

http://jsonapi.org/format/#query-parameters
http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes

Alternatively, you could /v1/comments?include=articles&filter[articles]=1&page[size]=2

See http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering
and http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-pagination